# IOS Swift Dismiss Tab Bar Controller and launch a new one

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller

long time listener, first time caller.

I'm working on an app that consists of a login page (View Controller) and then dismisses to reveal a tab bar controller with 4 tabs, each with a Navigation Controller with their own views.

I'm looking to allow a user to click a "Logout" button that dismisses all the views associated with the Tab Bar Controller, segues to the Login View Controller, and then instantiates a new Tab Bar Controller. Without dismissing and creating a new Tab Bar Controller, all of the Tab views hold the old user data, since they are populated with "ViewDidLoad" functions.  Unless there is another way to clear and trigger the "ViewDIdLoad" functions without dismissing all of the views/tab bar controller.

I'm open to other solutions as well since I'm very new to IOS Swift programming and am self taught.

My structure looks like this (note that the app enters the Tab Bar Controller first, if no current user is found it kicks back to the Login View Controller which dismisses itself upon login):[Login/Tab Bar Controller relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dphbi.png)

Comment: when user logout then you have to set rootviewcontroller programically and take one bool for check user login or not so you can easily manage your tabbar

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Thank you for the suggestion. I think that is what gabriel suggested below. Im just not sure if this automatically dismisses the first view controller (so that it's not still lingering somewhere) and if that setting a new rootviewcontroller is a good practice. I'm going to implement the solution and report back.

Comment: your problem solve or not ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Just implemented your solution as described also by Gabriel below. It appears to function exactly the way I need it too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storyboard looks a bit confusing. I asume the app loads the Tab Bar the first and then, the login view controller is presented modally. But then, what is the segue from Login to Tab Bar? a push segue? I suppose it is not used and the login, as you say, is just dismissed.

To destroy the Tab Bar and load a new one from the storyboard you cannot use segues. It's even easier. Just have to assign a new instance of Tab Bar to rootViewController of the window of your app.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = theNewTabBar
```

And to instantiate that "theNewTabBar", you will need to set an identifier in the storyboard and use

```
storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thanks.  Correct, the segue from Login to TabBar is unused. Again Correct, the login page is being dismissed.  My follow up question is: Is it a good practice to assign a new rootViewController? As per my title you've certainly answered my question, but I've heard mixed reviews on doing such. Is there a better practice to reload all the views in a TabBar (dismissing them separately seems inefficient)? The script you provide would be in the Login page on "view did load" or is there a better way to call it in response to the segue?

Comment: Also, just for clarification before I make any changes, when I dismiss the Login page after the new rootviewcontroller has been created. Will it return to the rootviewcontroller or will I need an additional segue?

Comment: @Xion If you want to avoid setting a new roootViewController, you can subclass the tab bar and add a method that inits user data and sets new ViewControllers. That is, you instantiate the view controllers for the tabs, and set an array with the new instances. The old ones will be destroyed automatically.

Comment: Hey Gabriel, I think I understand subclassing the tab bar for the user data, but when you say "instantiate the view controllers for the tabs" is where I get lost. I would give each view controller a name and initialize them separately? How would this destroy the old view controllers? Wouldn't I just have multiple instances of the views?

Answer (score 0):

You can Store Flag to check whether user is Logged in or not. On application loading time You Should open first LOGIN PAGE. BUT in LOGIN PAGE you have to check That flag.

> If it is true than page Should directly Redirect to TAB BAR. If it is
>   False than on Successful login you Should Set Flag True. At log OUT
>   you Should POP TAbBAR and set Flag False.

This is Better Structure. For setting flag with application scope you should store bool is user default..This is function to store flag and get flag.

```
//for set Bool
class func setUserDefaultBool (value : Bool, key : String){
       UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key)
       UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

//for get 
class func getUserDefaultBOOLForKey (key: String) -> Bool{
      return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: key)
}
```

Comment: Hi Anshul, you mention that "At log OUT you Should POP TAbBAR". Does the TabBar need to be embedded in a navigation controller in order to pop it? Or would this work if I just opened the login page first and then segued to the TabBar?

Comment: Hi, You Should have navigation Controller, the flow is NC->login-> tabbar